# Discrete mathematics, equivalence relations, functions.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

I'd like some insight on how to 'solve' this problem (more towards understanding what the problem is asking)

> Suppose that $A$ is a nonempty set and $\mathcal{R}$ is an equivalence relation on
>   $A$. Show that there is a function $f$ with $A$ as its domain such that $(x,y) \in \mathcal{R}$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$.

I do not understand the idea of "how to show that there is a function $f$". The elements of $A$ are arbitrary, so there is nothing specified about what's actually in $A$ other than it is a non-empty set. I also know that $\mathcal{R}$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

I feel that the function f is somewhat related to the relation $\mathcal{R}$ in the problem, and what I'm supposed to do is show that this function is $\mathcal{R}$.

Am I completely missing the point or am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

You are not completely missing the point, but you're a bit off the mark.

Firstly, let go of the fact that you know nothing about the elements of the set $A$. It really is not important. (Incidentally, the claim remains true even if $A$ is empty.) What you have to do is construct the function $f$. To construct a function you must specify its domain and codomain. In this case the domain is given to be $A$. You must figure out what the codomain of the function must be, and then you must define the function. Now, certainly, the fact that you are given an equivalence relation on $A$ is crucial. So, what would be a natural candidate for the codomain of $f$? In your studies of equivalence relations, have you seen how to construct the quotient set? It's the set of equivalence classes: $A/{\sim} = \{[x]\mid x\in A\}$. Can you now think of a function $f\colon A\to A/\sim$? There is really only one sensible way for defining such a function, and then you'll be able to show it satisfies the required property.

Comment: I have not come across the term 'quotient set' (cool to know that there is such a thing though!), nonetheless, what you've told me makes a lot of sense as it follows from content I've covered (such as equivalence classes). I can now work away on the little details, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate the problem into simpler terms.

You are given a set $A$ and an equivalence relation $R$.

You want a function f on A such that two conditions hold:

1. If $x$ is equivalent to $y$, then $f$ takes on the same value for both.
2. If $x$ is not equivalent to $y$, then $f$ must take distinct values for $x$ and $y$

In symbols,

- condition 1 is $(x,y) \in R \implies f(x)=f(y) $
- condition 2 is $(x,y) \notin R \implies f(x) \neq f(y) $

Of course, condition 2 is logically equivalent to the converse of condition 1. Hence, these two conditions together is the logically equivalent to $(x,y) \in R \iff f(x)=f(y)$

If you've already learnt that an equivalence relation partitions a set into equivalence classes, then the answer is simple.  Condition 1 requires that a function is constant on each equivalence class; and condition 2 requires that the function does not take on the same value for members from two different equivalence classes.  This implies that we can choose $f$ to have any codomain which has cardinality greater than or equal to the cardinality of the set of equivalence classes.  In short, each equivalence class needs its very own object to map to, so each element in $A$ should be sent to the object associated with the equivalence class to which the element belongs.

The following picture is great to keep in mind, replacing "S" with $A$
[image: An excellent picture to keep in mind]
<sub>(source: [uah.edu](http://www.randomservices.org/random/foundations/Equivalence.png))</sub>

Each colored box is an equivalence class.

$f$ takes every element in the red box to the "red dot" in $T$,
every element in the green box to the "green dot" and so on...